# Fast manipulation of drawImage() brightness in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've made a tile based game and I'm using the 2D canvas context to render the tiles. Only the tiles in view are rendered, about 800 at a time. Each tile is 10x10 pixels, stretched to 40x40. I need to individually control each tile's brightness. Without adjusting the brightness of the tiles, it has a constant 60 fps, even on mobile browsers.

The first way I tried to change the brightness of the tiles was using the `ctx.filter` property, e.g. `ctx.filter = 'brightness(<brightnessValue>)';`, but this was really slow, and gave about 10 fps.

I then tried drawing the image to another smaller canvas, getting the image data, multiplying the RGB values by `<brightnessValue>` and then putting this image data onto the main canvas. This worked, but was only slightly better, giving around 14 fps, which was still unusable.

The last way I tried was to draw a semi-transparent square over each tile, except the performance was still bad, about 30 fps when all tiles where on-screen. There were also 1 px gaps between the squares, and when I tried increasing the size of the squares by one pixel, the overlap, due to the transparency and blending, caused a similar line.

Here is the latest function I wrote to draw the tiles:

```
function renderImage(assetID, width, height, posX, posY, rotation, brightness) {
    let x = w / 2 - (cameraX - posX); // calculate the x position to draw the image on the display
    let y = h / 2 + (cameraY - posY); // calculate the y position to draw the image on the display

    if (x > -width && x < w + width && y > -height && y < h + height) { 
        let image = getEntityImage(assetID);
        rotation *= 0.01745329; // // convert degrees to radians
        ctx.translate(x, y); 
        ctx.rotate(rotation);
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height); // draw the image
        if (brightness && brightness != 1) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + (brightness > 1 ? '255,255,255,' : '0,0,0,') + Math.abs(1 - brightness);
            ctx.fillRect(-width/2-1, -width/2-1, width+2, width+2); // draw the image
        }
        ctx.rotate(-rotation); // reset rotation
        ctx.translate(-x, -y); // reset translation
    }
}
```

and here's the code that calls calls the above function:

```
for (let y = ylimN; y <= ylimP; y++) {
    for (let x = xlimN; x <= xlimP; x++) {
        let xp = x * 40;
        let yp = y * 40;
        let blockVal = map[x + y * mapWidth]; // get the value of the block: (0 for air, 1 for grass etc.)
        if (blockVal > 0) renderImage(blockVal, 40, 40, xp, yp, 0, brightnessValue);
    }
}
```

What options are there for changing the brightness of an image drawn with drawImage() that will give at least 60 fps? Or should I just redo all the rendering using WebGL, which would be a big pain?

EDIT: After testing the rectangle overlaying method further, it seems that the drop in performance with the rectangles overlaid on the tiles is only a problem with Chrome (on all platforms). On Firefox, it's able to maintain a constant 60 fps, and there aren't even any gaps due to anti-aliasing. The same is true for iOS Safari, macOS Safari and Firefox on Android. I really do need it to work on Chrome, so I think my best option would be to use WebGL.

I learned more about WebGL, vertex shaders and fragment shaders, and made a few projects using them, and I've found that it is not as challenging to do what I want as I'd initially thought, and it'll also allow me to create smooth lighting and other effects on the blocks through slightly more advanced shaders, so it definitely has benefits other than performance. I've therefore started altering it to use WebGL. Writing code for the GPU is surprisingly interesting.

I will post a link to the original code as well as the code with WebGL implemented when I'm done, for anyone interested.

Comment: Are all your graphics upscaled by a factor of 4? Because you could use a canvas that has the same resolution as your tiles and display it at four times the size instead, that should improve the drawing time considerably.

Comment: I considered that, except it has numerous problems. If I render each block to take up 10x10 pixels of the canvas, instead of 40x40, I would have to reduce the canvas size by a factor of four, to get the same number of blocks on the screen, and then I would need to use CSS to make it take up the whole width and height of the display, except each pixel of the canvas would then use 16 pixels on the display, which looks very ugly when in motion (because 4 px is the minimum jump of an object's position), even with `image-rendering: pixelated;`

Comment: Maybe you can use this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

Comment: Unfortunately this radically reduces the fps and uses 80% GPU, 60% CPU. It's starting to look like WebGL would be a better and more efficient option.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal playground for us to tweak on instead of having to rewrite everything from scratch? The problem with your fillRect is that after rotation, you are forced to have antialiasing. To avoid that, you would have to perform the compositing first and then rotate, but without seeing the full setup, it's hard to tell if it's at all doable.  Also it's quite strange drawing the rect over make the perfs that bad, but a simple way to fix that is to build only two pathes made of all the rects of each color.